# Pushing text with fancy quotes to git mangles them

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am checking in code (to Bitbucket) with the following:

```
setting “The Gold Standard in Private Dispute Resolution” by
```

When I look at it in Bitbucket, the fancy quotes (“”) are mangled.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is that supposed to be? Commit message, source code? Just because it can't display it on the page doesn't mean it can't be viewed correctly somewhere where the characters are supported

Comment: Yes, looks like a display issue on the bitbucket page. No reason to think anything is mangled in the commit itself. These chars are no different from any other unicode chars. Which are handled perfectly in git.